# jquery Add number of months to start date

Tags: jquery, date

I want to add X number of months to my selected date from date picker,and number of months from my dropdown, I'm using below code:

```
 $('#start_date').change(function(){
 var months = $('#month_number').val(); 
 var end = new Date($(this).val());
 end.setMonth(end.getMonth() + months);  
 $('#date_hid_m').val( (end.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + end.getDate() + '/' + end.getFullYear()) ;
```

But the result is incorrect. E.g: if my start date is: MAY 28, 2016 and i want to add 6 months, the result shows 11/28/2019 !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `months` is a string, because its value is retrieved from an `input` text element. So its value will get ***concatenated*** to `end.getMonth()`, not added as a number. You're getting 56 (=5+'6') months instead of 11 (=5+6) months there.

Solve this by converting the string to a number with a `+`:

```
var months = +$('#month_number').val();
```